# How to request cross-domain for xml on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show yahoo news feeds in my website, so I need to read [Yahoo rss](http://news.yahoo.com/rss/).

How to request it, with javascript? Do "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" let it go?

Comment: What else do you have ? Any code ?

Comment: @Milche Patern. I tried with $.ajax() simple page,but I blocked by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. so i think it may be happened for xml too

Comment: You can use EasyXDM http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Answer (score 1):

XML won't run cross-site like that. You could convert it to json using something like Yahoo Pipes.

Using this pipe http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=DJEg41Ac3BG8IAI2E5PZnA
and configuring with **url**:`http://news.yahoo.com/rss/` and **path**:`channel.item`

You can make json output by grabbing the "Get as JSON" link that gives you this url:  http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=DJEg41Ac3BG8IAI2E5PZnA&_render=json&path=channel.item&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.yahoo.com%2Frss%2F

And here's a jsfiddle using that pipe http://jsfiddle.net/5KM4X/

If you don't want to rely on Pipes, you could write a local server side script that does nothing by proxy the remote url and expose it's output. Using PHP, you could have a file called

`getFeed.php`

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo file_get_contents("http://news.yahoo.com/rss");
```

And then access it (using jquery here)

```
 $.get('getFeed.php', function(xml){
 ....
```

Comment: nice, Do pipe request has limit access (e.g 1000 per day or ...)?

Comment: Looks like it's 20 calls / minute with no daily limit but if you exceed you get blocked for an hour. [Pipes FAQ](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=troubleshooting#q15)